# How can I create a link based on part of a URL, for each link already in a table?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm feeling fairly frustrated, because I feel like this is probably very easy/obvious and I'm just not putting the pieces together. I'm trying to create a GM script that will look at each URL in a table, extract one piece of each URL (unique for each entry), and then insert a *new* link that'll appear after each entry.

Here's an example of what the HTML would look like:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="400">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="http://website.com/names/1936">joseph smith</a>
    </td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="http://website.com/names/1756">john smith</a>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="http://website.com/names/350466">scott smith</a>
    </td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="http://website.com/names/789533">adam smith</a>
    </td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like, for each entry, to identify the number that comes after "/names/", which is unique to each name and is not always the same length. Then I'd like to insert a new link *after* the one already there, like this:

```
<a href="http://website.com/names/[number]/edit">[number]</a>
```

For a basic example of how it would look, I'd like this (for each entry):

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="http://website.com/names/1936">joseph smith</a> <a href="http://website.com/names/1936/edit">1936</a>
    </td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. As I said, I feel as if I'm a bit dense, and that this should be a lot simpler than I'm making it out to be. I've been trying to figure it out for days, and I can't seem to get anywhere (I'm not fully proficient at javascript yet!).

**Update**: for clarification, my difficulty is doing what I believe are three things:
1) identifying these specific URLs (as opposed to any other that might appear elsewhere in the table or page
2) extracting the number from the URLs
3) inserting the new link after each of these links

I don't have the ability to change the HTML code already there, to give IDs for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete script that shows how to do this using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), and with CSS styling to make it look better:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add edit links after user links
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

//--- This next selector is highly page-specific.
var nameLinks   = $("td a[href*='names']");
nameLinks.each ( function () {
    /*---   From: <a href="http://website.com/names/1756">john smith</a>
            Make: <a href="http://website.com/names/1756/edit">Edit user 1756</a>
            (Plus some housekeeping.)
    */
    var newURL  = this.href.replace (/names\/(\d+)$/i, "names/$1/edit");
    var userNum = RegExp.$1;    // Special feature of replace().

    $(this).after (
        '<a href="' + newURL + '" class="gmEditLink">Edit user ' + userNum + '</a>'
    );
} );

GM_addStyle ( '                         \
    a.gmEditLink {                      \
        margin-left:            1em;    \
        font-size:              80%;    \
        vertical-align:         super;  \
    }                                   \
' );
```

Comment: Thank you so very much - this perfectly fits my needs, and I'll be able to use the code to figure out how to do similar actions elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

```
var slash=str.lastIndexOf("/");
var number=str.slice(slash);
```

where str is a string containing the url. First line gets the position of the last / in the string, the second line slices the string from the index of that / to the end of the string, giving you everything after the / in the url

"number" will then be a variable representing those digits

give the table an ID, id="mytable". You will need to include the jQuery library for this to work.

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var url= $(this).find("td:first").html();
    //at this point url holds the contents of the entire td

});
```

.. you can then use a series of "lastIndexOf" and "slice" statements to trim the area around the url to isolate the information you need

try this,

```
var count = 1
$('table').each(function(){
   (this).attr("id", "table"+count);
   count++;
});
```

this will assign an id to each table on the page. so the first table will then have an id of table1 and the second will be table2.

then you can use the function (I'm assuming it's the second table you want),

```
$('#table2 tr').each(function() {
    var url= $(this).find("td:first").html();
    //at this point url holds the contents of the entire td
});
```

And, as above, use the indexOf and slice functions to isolate your number

Comment: The problem I seem to be having is fitting all the "pieces" of the script together: having the script specifically identify the table entries' URLs (as opposed to any others appearing on the page), grabbing the number, and then inserting the new link immediately after the other link. These are all individual bits that seem simple enough on their own, but when I try to put them all together, my eyes go crossed and nothing works right. :(

Comment: This can be accomplished using jQuery. I will update my answer

Comment: Sorry to cause trouble, but I don't have control over the HTML code already in place, so I can't give the table an ID myself, right?

Comment: no, you wouldn't. How many tables are on this page? jQuery can help with that

Comment: There's 2 tables, one based on search options and then the second that lists the names that come up with the search (which is basically like the example I've given above). The table of names is drawn from a larger index, so it potentially changes each time, as it gets updated with new information. And then there's, of course, other content on the page before and after the tables (header/footer info relevant to the site). I'm not too familiar with jQuery; I was hoping I'd be able to come up with a simple GM script...maybe that's why I've had such trouble figuring it out! :P

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible (and perhaps less complex) to use RegEx somehow to identify the "a href" parts?

Comment: Yes its definitely possible, many ways to tackle this problem

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. I'll be able to use this info on another bit I'm working on, as I learn to work with jQuery more. I appreciate the time and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume using jQuery is ok here. I have tried to comment this fairly verbosely to give you a good idea of what is happening at each step

```
// Get all <a> tags within the table and loop over them
$("table a").each( function() {
    // Get the url this <a> tag points to
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    // Parse the id using regex (find a string of numbers following a "/"
    var userId = url.replace( /.*\/(\d+).*/, "$1" );

    // Create the new, desired, url
    var newUrl = "http://website.com/names/" + userId + "/edit/";

    // Append the new link after this <a> tag
    $(this).after( "<a href='" + newUrl + "'>" + userId + "</a>" );
} );
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Please only give jQuery answers to javascript questions when either (a) jQuery is specified/asked-for, or (b) you show the readers -- many of whom are newbies -- HOW to switch to jQuery.  Other than that, this answer is the right idea.

Comment: I'm needing to learn to switch to jQuery, it seems, so I appreciate the example, as well as the commenting to explain each step.